# How to move to Windows 10 when using apps on SD card?

Tags: apps, insider-preview, storage, micro-sd

Some months back I got the message on my Lumia 640XL that I could try/move to Windows 10. I did, but since I have all my apps on SD card and the internal memory does not have enough memory to fit all apps, a lot of apps did not work anymore.

Luckily I could revert back and have Windows 8 again.

However, eventually I want to use Windows 10 again, but do I something wrong or do I have to wait until Windows 10 supports app storage on SD cards like Windows 8? For me, this is one of the key features I need.

Comment: Are you on build 10581?

Comment: Are you using an insider build? Whilst it has been reported that Windows 10 Mobile is due to roll out in November 2015, I'm not aware of it having been released other than through the insider program.

Comment: @Shawn: I don'tn know which built, OS version 8.10.15148.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Looks indeed I had installed an insider built ... guess I will wait until the official release comes (with the SD storage feature).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wait : the current mobile build has a little bug with the storage setting.

If you move from WP8 to W10M, your apps on the SD card will still be there.
But with the current build we can't change the storage settings, so you should set them up before upgrading.

Comment: I have since last week installed Windows 10 again and now everything works as expected.